# python matplotlib dash-dot-dot - how to?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linestyle

I am using python and matplotlib to generate graphical output.
Is there a simple way to generate a dash-dot-dot line-style?
I am aware of the `'--'`, `'-.'`, and `':'` options. Unfortunately, `'-..'` does not result in a dash-dot-dot line.
I have looked at the `set_dashes` command, but that seems to control the length of the dashes and the space between two adjacent dashes.
One option may be to plot two lines on top of each other; one dashed with ample space between the dashes - and one dotted, with the dots as large as the dashes are wide and spaced so that two dots are in between each of the dashes. I do not doubt this can be done, I am simply hoping for an easier way.
Did I overlook an option?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can define [custom dashes](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/dash_control.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line, = plt.plot([1,5,2,4], '-')
line.set_dashes([8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

`[8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]` means

- 8 points on,  (dash)
- 4 points off,
- 2 points on,  (dot)
- 4 points off,
- 2 points on,  (dot)
- 4 points off.

---

@Achim noted you can also specify the `dashes` parameter:

```
plt.plot([1,5,2,4], '-', dashes=[8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4])
plt.show()
```

produces the same result shown above.