# Change spacing of dashes in dashed line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line, subplot

In Python, using matplotlib, is there a way to change the distance of the dashes for different linestyles, for example, using the following command:

```
plt.plot(x,y,linestyle='--')
```

Comment: Wouldn't using custom linestyles do? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710221/python-matplotlib-dash-dot-dot-how-to)

Answer (score 100):

You can directly specify the dashes length/space using the `dashes=(length, interval space)` argument inside the plot command.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', dashes=(5, 1)) #length of 5, space of 1
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 2], linestyle='--', dashes=(5, 5)) #length of 5, space of 5
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 3], linestyle='--', dashes=(5, 10)) #length of 5, space of 10
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 4], linestyle='--', dashes=(5, 20)) #length of 5, space of 20
```

[image: lines]