# Matplotlib Forcing Dashed Line to Touch Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

Is there a way to force the dashed line of a plotted curve to touch both axes (top and bottom)? Specifically, I'm looking to find a way to specify the start position (xstart, ystart) and end position (xend, yend) of the dash so I can force it to touch the axes. Here's an example to show the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y = np.power(x,3.0)+80

plt.plot(x,y+5, '--')
plt.axis(xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=100,ymax=150)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Try `ylim` `xlim` to arbitrarily set your intercepts relative to your data.

Comment: Doesn't this just make the plot window smaller? I would prefer to not have to sacrifice my plot range to get this to work.

Comment: I may have misunderstood then. Could you give a full executable yet minimal example showing the problem?

Comment: I edited to include the code. I want the dashed line to touch the bottom y-axis at y=100 and the top y-axis at y=150.

Comment: You mean top and bottom x-axes at y=100 and 150? That's what the picture shows and what I see when I run your example. Only difference is that the dash is 'off' at first, so it appears disconnected, but by no more than one dash-length.

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710221/python-matplotlib-dash-dot-dot-how-to  for finer dash control and how in that example the lines are touching. So I was wrong, the dash style should always start with the dash 'on' and it should fit up to the line as you requested.

Comment: This seems to be just a way to modify the frequency and separation of the dashes. I'm looking for a way to hard code the start and end dash locations with (x,y) values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106549/discussion-between-roadrunner66-and-grover).

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment by roadrunner66 I assembled an example that works for me

```
l, = plt.plot(x,y+5)
l.set_dashes([5,2])
plt.axis(xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=100,ymax=150)
```

[image]

If you want to automate this, I guess one needs to know the length of your line as well in order to calculate the right dashes.

To obtain the length of the line in [display coordinates](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) could do something like

```
xl,yl=l.get_xydata().T
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

# Filter out the points outside the range & replace them with a point on the axis
m = ((xl >= xmin) & (xl <= xmax)) & ((yl >= ymin) & (yl <= ymax))
x = np.concatenate([[xmin], xl[m], [xmax]])
y = np.concatenate([[ymin], yl[m], [ymax]])
xt, yt = ax.transData.transform(np.vstack([xl,yl]).T).T
length = np.sum( np.sqrt((xt[1:] - xt[:-1])**2 + (yt[1:] - yt[:-1])**2))
```

Now given this length we can calculate a reasonable tick length & spacing in between

```
length = np.sum( np.sqrt((x[1:] - x[:-1])**2 + (y[1:] - y[:-1])**2))
tickl = 5.
minspace = 2.
i = int(length / (tickl + minspace))
space = length / i - tickl # since length = i * (space + tickl)
print space
```

This gives me a value of `2.39086935951` so 2 wasn't a too bad guess.

Comment: You can also do this as `plt.plot(x, y, linestyle=(0, [5, 2])`.  The 0 is the 'offset' (how many pixels into the cycle the 'start' is and works properly on the 2.x and master branches (but not in any released version of mpl :/)

Comment: @tacaswell this now works in released versions! You should definitely submit an answer to this thread, as it solves the problem more simply. It should be the accepted solution.