# Creating custom dash-dot-dot linetype in ggplot - is it possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am remaking a set of maps using `ggplot` and `sf`, but need to delineate international borders with a dash-dot-dot linetype (it is a required UN standard).  This is not a default linetype in R or ggplot.

Does anyone know if there a way manually specify/apply user specified linetypes in R or ggplot?

In python and matplotlib it appears this is possible [python matplotlib dash-dot-dot - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710221/python-matplotlib-dash-dot-dot-how-to)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789410/1457051

Comment: Yes. It's detailed in the [`ggplot2` docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#lines)